# Html5 Download attribute not working in Firefox 38.0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

This is similar, but not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781801/html5-download-attribute-not-working-in-ff) question. In my situation, I am using FF 38.0.5(which is latest as of the time of writing this question).

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), it clearly says that

> In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources
>   with the same-origin.

Note that it says "In Firefox 20" and not "In Firefox 20 **Onwards**"
So it should not be the case in firefox 38.0.5.

Actually I have created a mashup widget for a third party website, so all the anchor links are of different domains. Its like an embedded html frame.

If I go for the proposed solution in the above SO question's answer(which deals with only image files), I would have to put the content type of each file and that would be very cumbersome as we would have to consider n different types of files.

So is there a way to get round this problem so that the cross domain anchors work in firefox(as well as chrome)?

**EDIT:**
In my case, the anchors are opening file in that frame instead of downloading that particular file.

Answer (score 2):

It is a security issue if Firefox obeys `download` attribute even cross-origin. There is a thorough discussion of this in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619 , notable with comments 34 and 35. So I believe the MDN wiki really means "since" Firefox 20.

Comment: Then there is no way to somehow make it work perhaps via jquery/javascript?(without having to simply mention content type for each type of file)

Comment: Right. The 3 proposed solutions in the above link are the only things you can do.

Comment: BTW, I fixed the MDN wiki page as well.

Comment: Duh! Thats too dissapointing to know :-( BTW are you somehow associated with MDN?(just curious as how could you edit that wiki)

Comment: No. MDN is just a wiki, similar to wikipedia. You can open an account and edit it. Be cautious and prudent, of course.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have upvoted your answer already. But would like to wait a bit more to accept as answer if someone comes up with something out of the box.

Comment: Sure! BTW, just to let you know that you can change the accepted vote any time in future.